# PHP and Jquery increase value

Tags: php, jquery

Regarding javascript:

I use client side to echo out the income of a value each hour from PHP. Finding out how much the value would increase each second.

```
 var resource1 = <? echo $this->user->maxincome($resourceincome[0]);?>;
    var persec1 = resource1/ (60*60);
```

There is also this further down in the body.

```
Wood: <span id="datawood" data-income="<?  echo $this->user->maxincome($resourceincome[0]);?>"><? echo number_format($village->wood); ?> / <? echo number_format($maxstorage);?>
```

Based on `persec1` how can I increase the value and data-income value of `datawood` ?

Below is what I have tried but the 0.25 won't be added to the value.

```
a = $("#datawood").data('income');
b = a + 0.25;
$("#datawood").data('income', b);
```

**This is to increase the value based on resource1, each sec, based on resource1 variable that holds the raise each hour**

**Regarding the PHP:**

If I have a variable that holds how much income it is per hour, what would the best way of sending this to the user? This need to be every second so a cron job may be to slow.

Comment: `data-income` is a string, you have to cast it as a number before adding to it.

Comment: how would i do that @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard jQuery parses numeric strings into numbers for you, to varying degrees of usefulness and head-banging-against-desk depending on whether you actually wanted strings or numbers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol want the decimals to be in data-income, but the avual value inside the datawood to the nearest int of that.

Comment: I mostly get the head-banging-against-desk kind @NiettheDarkAbsol, which is why I suggest casting. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The code works as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/kmqjxzkt/